# Editing limit.conf in Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to run this command so I can install Websphere Portal in Ubuntu:

```
sudo echo "@users soft nofile 10240" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

But every time I try I get `"Permission Denied"` message. I'm running an Ubuntu Server 12.04 Virtual Box (no graphic interface) and every solution I found on the Web requires the use of Gedit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo` happens as root. The redirection happens as the current user. Clearly this is not what you want.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "@users soft nofile 10240" >> /etc/security/limits.conf'
```